# Sql Server stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I create a sales order, the table structure is

Order

```
       pack_ID       qty
       -----------------
          4          500
```

Product Stock

```
       pack_ID     batchNO      qty    mfgDate
       ---------------------------------------
          4        ABC01       200    01/01/2010
          4        XYZ02      1000    01/01/2010
```

So I would like to get products in Invoice as

```
       pack_ID     batchNO      qty   
       ------------------------------
          4        ABC01       200   
          4        XYZ02       300
```

Comment: Give an explanation where 200 and 300 in results came from.

Comment: 300 xyz02 is required to make the qty of 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive queries to satisfy this efficiently.

Don't worry about the data types not matching your table, the important bit is that they order correctly.

```
/*
create table orders (pack_id int, qty int)
insert orders select 4, 500

create table stock (pack_id int, batchno int, qty int, mfgdate int)
insert stock select 4,1,200,1
insert stock select 4,3,1000,2
*/

-- target qty for a pack_id, or set these are SProc params
declare @packid int set @packid = 4
declare @qty int set @qty = 500

;with A as (
select *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by mfgdate, batchno)
from stock
where pack_id = @packid),
B as (
select pack_id, batchno, qty=case when qty>@qty then @qty else qty end, mfgdate, to_go=@qty-qty, rn
from A
where rn=1
union all
select A.pack_id, A.batchno, case when A.qty>to_go then to_go else A.qty end, A.mfgdate, @qty-A.qty, A.rn
from A
inner join B on A.rn=B.rn+1
where to_go > 0
)
select pack_id, batchno, qty, mfgdate
from B
order by mfgdate asc, batchno asc
```

The first CTE sets up the row numbers so that the 2nd CTE can go through them sequentially (you cannot use TOP/aggregates in the recursive portion of CTE); then the 2nd one collects stock until the quantity is satisfied